# What does this alternator diode test tell me?

Tags: alternator, mercedes-benz, diode, clk-500

I have the battery disconnected (pos and neg), and nothing is connected to my alternator.
When I connect a multimeter's common (black) to the positive pin and the red to the alternator housing, I get a reading of around 500. If I test it the other way around, I get a reading of 0. I read this is correct and indicates the diodes in the alternator are working correctly.

But as soon as I attach the alternator's positive pin to its cable (the battery is still completely unconnected) and repeat the same tests, I get positive readings both ways, indicating that the diodes are bad.

I am sure this tells me something, but what does it mean? Why does that happen?
(Because of this, I replaced the alternator, but the "new/used" one does the same thing.) I'm sure it is something down the line, but I want some help finding the problem. (The battery is draining, and electrical problems)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle you're working on?

Comment: Thank you. It is a 2006 Mercedes Benz CLK-500. I believe it is a 5.0 L V8

Comment: I know you're talking in generalities about your testing, however, some alternators may behave differently. Knowing what you're working on specifically will allow us to give you a better answer for your specific needs, so I appreciate you providing the information.

Comment: No problem. I can also tell that I know that the positive alternator wire goes to the starter and then to the battery. (based on an image here https://www.mercedesbenz.parts/v-2006-mercedes-benz-clk500--base--5-0l-v8-gas/electrical-equipment-and-instruments--battery-starter-alternator-cable).